# TreeMap does not compare every element in the map

Tags: java, treemap

This is a general question to ask:
I am writing a custom comparator in TreeMap to compare a custom class A (defined by myself). What I found is that when I keep adding key-value pair into the treemap, the newly added key does not compare every key in the treemap, instead it only compares a few keys at the bottom and skips some keys at the top. So that there are duplicate keys in the treemap.

Does anyone have this question before? Again this is a general question to ask, the code especially the dataset used to test is not open to public.

Comment: Are you sure you are imposing a "total ordering" in your comparator function? You do not provide any specifics, so it hard to provide a more detailed answer.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: are you sure you're `A` classes equals/hashcode is setup correctly?

Comment: What it sounds like is that your custom comparator is broken.  A properly written comparator won't _have_ to compare every key in the map.

Comment: But is there a way to compare all the keys? Because what I care about is equal rather than bigger or less. @Louis Wasserman

Comment: What do you mean you _care about_ is equal rather than bigger or less? Do you expect to encounter all elements in your comparator when you insert an element? Please give a code example of your problem.

Comment: Care about equal means what I want to achieve is to find distinct keys. Let's say we have three key-value pairs (P1,V1), (P2,V2), (P3,V3) and assume P1 is equal to P2 and not equal to P3, I want the result put in the treemap to be (P1,[V1,V2]) and (P3,V3) and I do not care about the order as long as the same key can be grouped together and be treated as the same key-value pair

Comment: There is no built-in `Map` implementation that compares all the keys.  All of the existing `Map` implementations, including `TreeMap`, assume you have some information that will help you figure out a smaller number of keys you will have to check for equality (either by binary search via a comparator, or a hash code in `HashMap`).

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is a `Map<P, List<V>>`, but you will need `P` to have a correct `Comparator`, `Comparable`, or `hashCode` and `equals` implementation.

Comment: Agree with Louis. If order doesn't matter, a normal `HashMap` will be your fastest option. You will then have to implement `hashCode` and `equals` on the class of the key, no need for a Comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The `TreeMap` class is implemented as a binary search tree. As such, it will only need to access up to the base-2 logarithm of the total number of nodes. You can see this behavior for yourself in the [`TreeMap.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java) implementation, where the code determines whether it needs to access the left or right child node. For details, check out the `put()` and `get()` method implementations.

Comment: But is there a way to compare all the keys? Because what I care about is equal rather than bigger or less.

Comment: The behavior of `TreeMap` is that it replaces the value with the new value when it finds an equivalent key. See line 558 of the link I posted in the answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So you mean I need to fix the source code? I wonder is there a easy fix available?

Comment: @teddy it is very likely that implementing a normal, correct comparator will be easier than trying to write an implementation that compares all the keys.

Comment: You almost never want to implement your own Tree. There are several implementations in the JDK that work extremely well for almost every situation. As @LouisWasserman pointed out, it is very likely, you need to use a Map<Key, List<Value>>, mos tlikely with a HashMap for speed. The only details you have to handle are writing the comparator and adding values for the same key to the List.